# How to display lat/long markers on google map v2 android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm currently working on an android app with web services, using an external database. The app consists of several tasks and each task is assigned to each camera id. Each camera have specific long/lat stored in the database. So right now when I select a specific task, there would be a guide button showing the user current location as a marker in the google map. I want to display the long/lat of the task as a marker on the google map, so there would be 2 marker. Just need some help with the android coding. Any help would be appreciated!

**GoogleMapActivity.java**

```
public class GoogleMapActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
 GoogleMap map;
 private String cameraid;

  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_map);

   LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

   lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

   map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
    .getMap();

  }

  @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   map.clear();

   MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

   mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

   mp.title("My Current Location");

   map.addMarker(mp);

   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16));

  }
@Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

}
```

**AcceptTask.java**

```
public class AcceptTask extends SherlockActivity {

    private static String sendingURL,
                          url,
                          imageURL,
                          dateTimeP,
                          notificationID,
                          cameraID;
    private String check = null;
    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_GET = "jobViewResult",
                                TAG_IMAGEURL = "imageurl",
                                TAG_MESSAGE = "vmessage",

                                TAG_GETA = "assignResult",
                                TAG_STATUS = "assignStatus";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

    private TextView tvCamera, tvDate;
    private ImageView my_image;
    // contacts JSONObject
    JSONObject api = null;
    private long userInteractionTime = 0;
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accept_task);

        tvCamera = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_CameraID);
        tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_DateR);
        my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_Task);
        //set the icon clickable
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        //add an < arrow on the icon
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

          File file = new File("/sdcard/LocationSystem/pendingtask_temp.jpg" );
           if (file.exists()) {
               file.delete();
           }


          if(isNetworkConnected()){
              try{
            // getting intent data
            Intent intent = getIntent();

            /** Get values from previous intent */
            dateTimeP = intent.getStringExtra("TAG_IMAGE_TIME_DATE_P");
            cameraID = intent.getStringExtra("TAG_CAMERA_ID_P");
            notificationID = intent.getStringExtra("TAG_NOTIFICATION_ID");

            /** Display cameraID and date time */
            tvCamera.setText(cameraID);
            tvDate.setText(dateTimeP);

            url = "url";

            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {
                api = json.getJSONObject(TAG_GET);
                check = api.getString(TAG_MESSAGE); 
                // Storing each json item in variable
                imageURL = api.getString(TAG_IMAGEURL);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(check.equals("Job available")){
            new DownloadImageTask().execute(imageURL);
            }else{
                AlertDialog.Builder builder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)); 
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setTitle("Job Unavailable");
                builder.setMessage(check);
             // Setting Icon to Dialog
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_error);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent loadIntent = new Intent();
                            loadIntent.putExtra("startUpdate_PList", "start");
                            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, loadIntent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                builder.show();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            if(e != null) {
                showServerErrorDialog();
            } 
        }
      }else{showNetworkErrorDialog();}
}

    private void showServerErrorDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)); 
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("Server Error");
        builder.setMessage("Server is currently unable to connect. Please check your network connectivity.");
     // Setting Icon to Dialog
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_error);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
        builder.show();
    }

    private void showNetworkErrorDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)); 

        builder.setTitle("No Network Connection");
        builder.setMessage("Please turn on your mobile 3G or connect to a network in order to use this application.");
     // Setting Icon to Dialog
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_error);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Close",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        AcceptTask.this.finish();
                    }
                });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Setting",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //calling setting menu
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }

    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
          ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
          if (ni == null) {
           return false;
          } else{
            return true;
         }
      }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle presses on the action bar items
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    if(my_image.getDrawable() != null){
                        File file = new File("/sdcard/LocationSystem/pendingtask_temp.jpg" );
                       if (file.exists()) {
                           file.delete();
                       }
                    }
                    Intent loadIntent = new Intent();
                    loadIntent.putExtra("startUpdate_PList", "start");
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, loadIntent);
                    finish();
                break;
                    default:
                        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }
                return false;
            }

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        userInteractionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        super.onUserInteraction();
        Log.i("appname","Interaction");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserLeaveHint() {
        long uiDelta = (System.currentTimeMillis() - userInteractionTime);

        super.onUserLeaveHint();

        if (uiDelta < 100){
            Logout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(isNetworkConnected()){
        try{
            SharedPreferences checkLogin1 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences( "checklogin", 0);
            String staffID = checkLogin1.getString("staffID", "");
            String staffPassword = checkLogin1.getString("password", "");

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //get the unique id
            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences( "checklogin", 0);
            String checkID = pref.getString("loginRID", "");

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

            // Read response data into buffer
            char[] buffer = new char[(int) responseEntity
                    .getContentLength()];
            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader.read(buffer);
            stream.close();

            JSONObject svr = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
            JSONObject obj = svr.getJSONObject("loginTestResult");
            String validation = obj.getString("valid");
            String position = obj.getString("position");
            String companyID = obj.getString("companyID");
            String messageStatus = obj.getString("message");
            if(validation.equals("1")){

                checkNotNull(SERVER_URL, "SERVER_URL");
                checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");
                // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
                GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
                // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
                // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
                GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
                //mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
                //gcmIDtxt =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.gcmID);
                registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
                final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this); 
                System.out.print(regId);
                if (regId.equals("")) {
                    // Automatically registers application on startup.
                    GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
                } else {
                    // Device is already registered on GCM, check server.
//                  if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
//                      // Skips registration.
//                      //mDisplay.append(getString(R.string.already_registered) + "\n");
//                      //gcmIDtxt.setText(regId);
//
//                  } else {
                        // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                        // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                        // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                        final Context context = this;
                        mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                boolean registered =
                                        ServerUtilities.register(context, regId);
                                // At this point all attempts to register with the app
                                // server failed, so we need to unregister the device
                                // from GCM - the app will try to register again when
                                // it is restarted. Note that GCM will send an
                                // unregistered callback upon completion, but
                                // GCMIntentService.onUnregistered() will ignore it.
                                if (!registered) {
                                    GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
                                }
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                                mRegisterTask = null;
                            }
                        };
                        mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
//                      }
                }

        }else{
            AlertDialog.Builder builder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)); 
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setTitle("Error");
                builder.setMessage(messageStatus + " Please sign in again.");
                // Setting Icon to Dialog
                builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            SharedPreferences pref2 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("checklogin", 0);
                            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = pref2.edit();
                            editor1.putInt("login", 0);
                            editor1.commit();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(AcceptTask.this, LoginPage.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                builder.show();
        }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                    if(e != null) {
                        showServerErrorDialog();
                    } 
                }
        }else{
            showNetworkErrorDialog();
        }
        //runAcceptedTask();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver =
               new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
             //mDisplay.append(newMessage + "\n");
            }
        };

    private void checkNotNull(Object reference, String name) {
           if (reference == null) {
               throw new NullPointerException(
                       getString(R.string.error_config, name));
            }
         }

    private void Logout(){
         if(isNetworkConnected()){
         try{
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //get the unique id
            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences( "checklogin", 0);
            String checkID = pref.getString("loginRID", "");
            String staffID = pref.getString("staffID", "");


            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

            // Read response data into buffer
            char[] buffer = new char[(int) responseEntity
                    .getContentLength()];
            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader.read(buffer);
            stream.close();

            JSONObject svr = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
            JSONObject obj = svr.getJSONObject("logoutResult");
            String messageStatus = obj.getString("userMessage");
            if(messageStatus.equals("Updated Successfully!!")){

                }else{
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)); 
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    builder.setTitle("Error");
                    builder.setMessage(messageStatus);
                 // Setting Icon to Dialog
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_error);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                    builder.show();
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                 if(e != null) {
                        showServerErrorDialog();
                    }
            }
         }
            else{
                showNetworkErrorDialog();
            }
     }


    //accept task button
    public void acceptTask(View v) {
        File file = new File("/sdcard/LocationSystem/pendingtask_temp.jpg" );
       if (file.exists()) {
           file.delete();
       }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AcceptTask.this);

        builder.setTitle("Confirm Accept");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure to accept this job?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(isNetworkConnected()){
                try{
                // Do do my action here
                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                        "checklogin", 0);
                String staffID = pref.getString("staffID", "");
                //sendingURL = ""+staffID;
                sendingURL = "url";

                // Creating JSON Parser instance
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(sendingURL);

                try {
                    api = json.getJSONObject(TAG_GETA);
                    check = api.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    if(e != null) {
                        showServerErrorDialog();}
                }
                if(check.equals("Job available")){
                    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(sendingURL);

                    try {
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You accepted the job.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent loadIntent = new Intent();
                        loadIntent.putExtra("startUpdate_PList", "start");
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, loadIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                         if(e != null) {
                                showServerErrorDialog();}
                }
                    }else{
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(AcceptTask.this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)); 
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.setTitle("Job Unavailable");
                        builder.setMessage(check);
                     // Setting Icon to Dialog
                        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_error);
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Intent loadIntent = new Intent();
                                    loadIntent.putExtra("startUpdate_PList", "start");
                                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, loadIntent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                        builder.show();
                    }


                } catch(Exception e) {
                    if(e != null) {
                        showServerErrorDialog();
                    } 
                }
                }else{
                    showNetworkErrorDialog();
                }

            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();


}

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

             // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/LocationSystem/pendingtask_temp.jpg");

                long total = 0;
                while((count = in.read(data)) != -1){
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                   File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "pendingtask_temp.jpg" );
                   if (file.exists()) {
                       file.delete();
                   }else{
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                   }
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                in.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                if(e != null) {
                    showServerErrorDialog();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
          // setting progress percentage
          pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/LocationSystem/pendingtask_temp.jpg";
            // setting downloaded into image view
            my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
            File file = new File("/sdcard/LocationSystem/pendingtask_temp.jpg" );
               if (file.exists()) {
                   file.delete();
               }
            if (my_image.getDrawable() == null){
                Toast.makeText(AcceptTask.this, "Please select again!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
          pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
          pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
          pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
          pDialog.setMax(100);
          pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
          //pDialog.setButton("Cancel", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null);
          pDialog.setButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            AcceptTask.this.finish();
                        }
                    });

          pDialog.setCancelable(false);
          pDialog.show();
          return pDialog;
        default:
          return null;
        }
      }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(my_image.getDrawable() != null){
            File file = new File("/sdcard/LocationSystem/pendingtask_temp.jpg" );
           if (file.exists()) {
               file.delete();
           }
        }
        Intent loadIntent = new Intent();
        loadIntent.putExtra("startUpdate_PList", "start");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, loadIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.accept_task, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. What is your problem? You have some error?

Comment: Yes my code is perfectly working. Now I just want to display the task's marker on the google map using the long/lat values from the database and I have some problem doing that.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I tried and not sure how to do it, do you have some reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an asynck task to get the DB values and call this task in onlocationchange.

Comment: Ok. then say the result.